# Wifi not see internal subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I have this connection diagram:
We need to access from 192.168.1.39 to the subnet 10.0.0.40 to see my octopi. I have a jaztell router for wan and the edge router x for office private network. If I connect on 10.0.0.40 ,I can see the wifi subnet and I can connect to the 192.168.1.39 but not inverse. How I can see the private subnet over wifi ?

Thanks! :) i'm very newbie on networking

Comment: "...to see my octopi" ? Is this some internet device, or a misspelling of octopuses, or octopodes? Is there any particular reason you need two different private IP subnets? Wouldn't it just be easier to merge them?

Comment: @tetsujin I believe an OctoPu is a Raspberry Pi / Pi type device designed to run Octopri t - ie allow 3d printing across a network.  I agree with your comment on subnets.

Comment: OctoPi It's a RasPi OS that turns Pi into an Octoprint controller. @Delirial, could you please edit your question to update it a little. 1) Please create an actual diagram like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/ae/62/27ae6275ad9e521fa26f641339770b45.png) so we can see what's connecting exactly where, with wire or wirelessly. 2) Please include the IP addresses of the devices. Doesn't need to be fancy, a hand-drawn one is enough. 3) Please add a screenshot of the LAN interface of your router. 4) Please clarify if you need to access the OctoPi only locally or also over the internet.

Comment: @Delirial Please note, there's no need to hide any IP addresses 192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x or 10.x.x.x, but please don't show your WAN port / internet port IP, i.e. your public IP.